# pyzor in Debian Testing

Tags: debian, email

It seems that the recent debian testing packages of Pyzor [1:0.5.0-3] has changed the content. Python scripts for pyzor are no longer included.

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/pyzor/filelist

- /usr/share/doc/pyzor/NEWS.gz
- /usr/share/doc/pyzor/README
- /usr/share/doc/pyzor/README.Debian
- /usr/share/doc/pyzor/THANKS
- /usr/share/doc/pyzor/changelog.Debian.gz
- /usr/share/doc/pyzor/copyright
- /usr/share/man/man1/pyzor.1.gz
- /usr/share/man/man1/pyzord.1.gz

Stable version [1:0.5.0-2] contains required scripts.
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/pyzor

- /usr/share/pyshared/pyzor/client.py
- /usr/share/pyshared/pyzor/server.py

What's the correct procedure of installing the pyzor client on Debian testing? Documentation does not mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=796488

Wait for it to be fixed and use the package from jessie in the meantime.

Comment: The  pyzor-0.5.0-3 bug [https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=796488] has been filled August 22. pyzor-0.5.0-3 was migrated to testing [https://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pyzor.html] on August 30 anyway.